# Disabling Verizon Galaxy S4 from sending usage data back to Verizon

Tags: rooting, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-4, verizon, data-monitoring

Its come to my understanding that Verizon gets information about how you use your phone reported back to it. Information such as "Amount of data used for Facebook, Snapchat, Netflix" etc. I know Verizon can always see the amount of data I used, but I'd rather keep the specific content/origination of the data private.

A friend told me that I can "root my phone and disable that reporting" but I didn't get all the information. I wanted to ask this community:

1. How to disable reporting back (hopefully without rooting the phone)
2. If rooting is required, what the most effective way of accomplishing all this is?

For some reason, googling around for this issue has given me no information! (I am a bit shocked at that as I figure it'd be a hot topic now-a-days).

FYI - In case you are curious, I do feel how I use data is a private matter and unless a company issues a warrant, should not look at the type of traffic I carry. Its just a principal I live by.

Note - Just in case, I am sure Verizon isn't specifically sniffing my packets. My concern is Verizon seeing things like:
100 Mbs on Facebook
200 Mbs on Snapchat
500 MBs on Netflix
etc
It just feels weird to me that they can see this information. 
I'd like to disable that reporting.

Lastly: I'm using a Verizon Samsung Galaxy S4 running KitKat 4.4.2, Kernel vs 3.4.0.

Comment: I'd press your friend for details, honestly. I doubt your phone is "sending" the data usage to Verizon at all. They're simply tracking your data usage themselves, on their switches and infrastructure. After all, they're effectively your ISP when using your phone's data connection. All of your traffic is travelling through them, and they (presumably) have lots of network monitoring tools in place that track packet destinations, origin, times, etc. A VPN might work to obfuscate this, if you're looking for something like that.

Comment: To be fair, my friend is on T Mobile. Perhaps they are different? As for VPN, that is an idea though I'd rather not add another layer + pay extra $

Comment: I can't imagine a situation where a carrier would be relying on the phone to communicate bandwidth usage in that way. All they're doing is monitoring the bandwidth used by your device as they handle it (again, it flows through their pipes, they can *already* track the bandwidth). Forcing the device to report its own usage somehow would be substantially more prone to error, and possibly even spoofing, which would greatly endanger the data packages sold by carriers (and therefore, their profit margins) which rely on accurate bandwidth accounting.

Comment: My friend told me the  name of the tracking system is Carrier IQ http://www.engadget.com/2011/12/01/carrier-iq-what-it-is-what-it-isnt-and-what-you-need-to/

Comment: This app will tell you for sure if you have Carrier IQ on your device. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.carrieriqdetector

Comment: @eldarerathis: Verizon **is** known to use hidden apps to track their customers. (But, now when I need the link, I can't find it.)

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way to block this, is by rooting your device, and remove or freeze the offending app. Try *TitaniumBackup*, *AppQuarantine* and *AFWall+*. But the simplest way, may be to try to install a `hosts` file that blocks all bad IP addresses, such as the one provided by [MoaAB](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1916098). You can try that without root, but I doubt it will work on your 4.4.2.

Answer (score -1):

I have the best way to do this, you must be rooted unfortunately.

You need to edit `build.prop` and add this line `ro.config.nocheckin` and put `true`.